# Invalid cast exception when triggering an HTMLEvent

Tags: c#, gecko, geckofx

I am using the following code to emulate a click event on a checkbox (which is used for a form validation, i.e. it needs to be clicked to 'activate' a button on a page).

```
        nsAStringBase eventType = (nsAStringBase)new nsAString("click");
        var ev = browser.Document.CreateEvent("HTMLEvents") ;
        ev.DomEvent.InitEvent(eventType, false, false);

var checkbox = (GeckoInputElement)taskRow.GetElementsByTagName("input")[2]; 
   checkbox.GetEventTarget().DispatchEvent(ev);
```

it used to work in Gecko 29 in winforms application. Now I have moved to WPF and a newer Gecko version, and I get an invalid cast exception - Cannot cast object of type Gecko.DomEventArgs to Gecko.DomMouseEventArgs.

I don't undertand why it stopped working. I tried casting explicitly, but it failed - and also I tried creating "MouseEvents" instead of "HtmlEvents" - this in turn does not throw any exception, but also does not 'activate' my button. CheckBox code is:

`<input type="checkbox" name="tsk" value="212654" onclick="ToggleCheck(this);">`

Thanks for help

Comment: Having the same problem, did you ever get this to work?

Comment: @Dagrooms - no, unfortunately not...